# Angular2 stop loading spinner after loading data with angularfire2

Tags: typescript, angular, angularfire2

I want to add a loading spinner to this component, and i'm trying to split the code into a service, so i can add a `.subscribe` method and **stop spinner when loading is done**, like in this working example:

> working example component

```
    ngOnInit(){
    this._userService.getUsers()
        .subscribe(users => {
            this.users = users;
            this.loadingUsers = false;
```

> working example service

```
    getUsers(){
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
```

> This is the component i'm trying to split:

```
    import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable , FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
    import {UserService} from './user.service';
    import {SpinnerComponent} from './spinner.component'

    export class UsersComponent implements OnInit{
      items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
             constructor(af: AngularFire) {
             this.items = af.database.list('/hr/users');
             //this.loadingLista = false;
            }
```

---

**Update#1 with a shot at the answer**

Trying a shot at the answer, to have a better understaning of the question.

So i created the UserService that will display the users using angularfire2 ,witch now i think is starting to be the main problem, and by that i mean the type of `items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;`

> UserService

```
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService{

    constructor(private _af: AngularFire){}

    getUsers(){
        return this._af.database.list('hr/users');
    }
}
```

> In UsersComponent i managed to get the list of users like this:

```
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  ngOnInit(){
     this.items = this._userService.getUsers(); 
  }
```

> But now i need a way to **stop the spinner after the loading is done**, and the only way i know is with `.subscribe()`:

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
loadingLista = true;

constructor(private _userService: UserService) {
}

  ngOnInit(){
      this._userService.getUsers();
      .subscribe(
        x => this.items = x,
        this.loadingLista = false
      )
  }
```

, but this doesn't work because of the tipe of `items`.
**Is there any other way to do this except `.subscribe()`? Or can i cast the type of `items` into something else?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I will add a shot at the answer, so it will be clearer i hope.

Comment: I guess the last problem in this scenario is the type of `items` that doesn't let me use the `.subscribe()` method to stop the spinner. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

just define it as `any`

```
items: any;
```

in the init block

```
  ngOnInit(){
          this._userService.getUsers()
          .subscribe(
            (x) => {this.items = x; this.loadingLista = false },
            (e) = > { console.log(error) },
          )
      }
```

in your html you cannot use async pipe...

```
<pre>{{ items | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: `this.items` is not assignable to type FirebaseListObservable<any>. That is the main problem i don't know how to pass.

Comment: `items: FirebaseListObservable<any>; `<== incorrect, see edits above

Comment: I changed all as u suggested, and in html i had `*ngFor="let item of items | async "` , witch i changed to `*ngFor="let item of items | json "`, but now i get `EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[.....`